# Are nuspec <dependencies> meant for runtime dependencies only?

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

Despite looking at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element), I am not clear on what this section is meant for. I don't see the point of specifying compile-time dependencies in it since the csproj has them and the DLL will be built at this point, so the dependencies don't need to be propagated further down (unless they're runtime). It's even counter-productive to do so because it creates unnecessary dependencies in the projects consuming the nuget, that may cause code scanners to complain about eventually for CVEs or whatnot.

Is my understanding correct?